# Input in div container, won't stretch

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing an input. I want the input to stretch to fill the available space, this works in Chrome but not IE and Firefox.

```
<div class="outer">
    <input type="text" />
</div>

.outer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;

    position: relative;
}

input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    right: 7px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/wwMZg/1/

---

In Chrome it appears like this:
[image: Chrome Screenshot]

In Firefox and IE it appears like this:
[image: IE Screenshot]

---

- In my real-use scenario there are other divs that contain images for corners, that's why the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` values are set to `7px` in this example.
- I would like to avoid setting the width directly on the `input`, I wan't to set it on `.outer`.

Comment: Is something wrong with doing this:  `.outer input { width: 100% }`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing `box-sizing: border-box` + `input { width: 100% }

Comment: @cimmanon Adding 100% width to the input will cause it to overlap on the right side of div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cant use `box-sizing` because you need to support older browsers, and don't mind adding another element to the markup, you can use an intermediate div

CSS

```
.outer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px; 
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    bottom: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    right: 7px;    
}

input{
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mFgR/

Comment: Thanks, I selected your answer because it works in all browsers.

Comment: You'll actually want to add the `box-sizing` to the input if you want the right side to be correct.  See http://jsfiddle.net/2mFgR/1/

Comment: @Drahcir yea `box-sizing` is nice, but not if you have to support older browsers

Answer (score 4):

Most input elements have padding/borders on them.  You need to use the box-sizing property to adjust how the element dimensions are calculated.

http://jsfiddle.net/wwMZg/5/

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}
.outer input {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing

Comment: Thanks, Looks good but didn't mark because there's not full support for `box-sizing` on older browsers.

Comment: Which browser does it *not* work on?  Note that you did not specify anything beyond IE, Chrome, Firefox and it works on *all* of those browsers if you ignore anything older than IE8 (which are practically nonexistant anyway)

Comment: You're right, IE 7 is the only one I think. But the more support the better, my site still gets a few visits from these users

Answer (score 0):

### Controlling the stretching and height of an input element

This styling problem is a bit intriguing since the `input` element seems to have its own set of rules.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}
.inner {
    margin: 7px;
}
input {
    font-size: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Wrapping the input field in the `.inner` element allows it to expand to 100% without triggering horizontal overflow on the top level container.

However, the margins will not be fully symmetric unless you set `border: none` on the input field.  This could be fixed using box-sizing to deal with the width of the borders.

With respect to the height property, `input` behaves like a regular inline, non-replaced element, that is, the height value does not apply and you need to use the font-size to get some control over the height.

See demo at **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/4NTUn/)**

Answer (score -2):

add width:100% to your input style

```
    .outer{
    width:100%;
    height: 40px;
    position:absolute;
 }

input{
    position:relative;
    top: 7px;
    bottom: 7px;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    border:1px solid gray;
}
```

It's the border that's offsetting it in IE

Comment: I would agree, but for some reason the OP is trying to avoid this. I don't think there's another way.

Comment: Adding 100% to the input will cause it to overlap on the right side of div

Comment: _"I would like to avoid setting the width directly on the input, I wan't to set it on .outer."_

Comment: I wouldn't mind setting setting 100% width on input, but only if it worked.

Comment: It works on your jsfiddle example with width:100%... in IE 10

Comment: @Rob Not for me on IE 9 or 10. http://jsfiddle.net/wwMZg/7/ Notice the overlap on the right side.

Comment: The problem is the `left` and `right` values being set to 7px, that's what causes the overlap on the right side.

Comment: No it's the box-sizing @cinnamon's solution fixes it